# How to make Many-to-one mapping without foreign key in EF Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core

Using EF Core 5.0, I have a PK-less entity (from a SQL view) `OrderInfo`, which has a column `OrderDetailId`. I also have an entity `DiscountOrder` which a PK from the columns `OrderDetailId` and `DiscountId`.

I would like to create a navigation property from `Order` to `DiscountOrders`. Such as:

```cs
public class OrderInfo
{
    public int OrderDetailId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DiscountOrder> DiscountOrders { get; set; }
}

public class DiscountOrder
{
    public int DiscountId  { get; set; }
    public int OrderDetailId  { get; set; }
}

// For reference, this entity also exists
public class Discount
{
    public int DiscountId { get; set; }
}
```

Obviously, there are no FKs to make use of, but I should be able to create a navigation property anyway.

I think I should be able to do this:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<OrderInfo>(e =>
{
    e.HasNoKey();

    e.HasMany(x => x.DiscountOrders)
        .WithOne()
        .HasPrincipalKey(o => o.OrderDetailId)
        .HasForeignKey(pb => pb.OrderDetailId)
        .IsRequired(false);
});
```

But a query on `DbSet<OrderInfo>` results in a `NullReferenceException` with the breakpoint landing on the `HasMany()` line. That said, I don't do anything with the `DiscountOrders` property, so the exception seems like it would have to be configuration related.

I've looked at answers to similar questions, but most answers use `HasOne().WithMany()` where as I'd like to keep this definition on `OrderInfo` since we don't really care about the other direction. How can I correctly set up this mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyless entities (entity without key) cannot be principal of a relationship, because there is no key to be referenced by the FK property of the dependent.

Note that by EF Core terminology key is *primary key*. There are also alternate (unique) keys, but EF Core does not enable them for keyless types.

So basically `HasNoKey()` disables alternate keys and relationships to that entity. Just the exception is unhandled, hence not user friendly. For instance, if you try to predefine the alternate key referenced by `.HasPrincipalKey(o => o.OrderDetailId)`  in advance

```
e.HasNoKey();
e.HasAlternateKey(o => o.OrderDetailId);
```

you'll get much better exception message at the second line

> The key {'OrderDetailId'} cannot be added to keyless type 'OrderInfo'.

Shortly, `e.HasNoKey();` and `.HasPrincipalKey(o => o.OrderDetailId); are mutually exclusive.

The only way to make it work is to define PK for `OrderInfo` even though it does not exist in database. In fact if `OrderDetailId` was supposed to be alternate key, in other words, is unique in the returned set, then you can safely map it as PK

```
//e.HasNoKey();
e.HasKey(o => o.OrderDetailId);
```

If it is not unique, then nothing can be done - you cannot map and use navigation property, and will be forced to use manual joins in L2E queries.

---

**Update:** EF Core also blocks changing "keyless"-ness once it's been set via fluent API (which has the highest configuration priority). So if you can't remove `HasNoKey()` fluent call because of it being generated by reverse engineering, you have to resort to metadata API to make it again "normal" entity by setting the [`IsKeyless`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.imutableentitytype.iskeyless?view=efcore-5.0) property to `false` before defining the key, e.g.

```
e.HasNoKey(); // generated by scaffolding

e.Metadata.IsKeyless = false; // <-- 
e.HasKey(o => o.OrderDetailId); // now this works
```

Comment: Hmmm... The automated scaffolding creates `entity.HasNoKey()` by default. I can't remove that as it is auto-generated. Adding `entity.HasKey(x => x.OrderDetailId)` after that doesn't help as I get the "cannot be added to a keyless type" exception you mentioned.

Comment: @DanFriedman This is one of the "little" details you should have provided in the question if you want to get a working solution. Anyway, answer updated, happy coding.